# Creating a faster way to <next error> -> <suggest fix> -> <accept fix>

Tags: lua

I'm using lazyvim with clangd extra installed, and when I have an error / diagnostic that needs handling I do the following routine:

1. `]d` / `]e` (go to next diagnostic / error)
2. `<LEADER>ca (i.e. space bar)` (code action - suggest a fix)
3. `enter` (accpet fix)

Is there a builtin faster way?

I have "Trouble" but that doesn't help me fix the issues, only to navigate them

Also, how can I customize this to suit my prefeneces? I'm imagining something like

1. `<leader> ff` ente fast-fix-errors pane
2. `n` go to next error and open the code actions (instead of `]e` + `<leader>ca`)
3. `N` go to next error and apply the first code action available